# DataBoundListAdapter with multiple item types

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components

I am using DataBoundListAdapter from android architecture components [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample).

I need to enhance it to support multiple item types. Anybody did it already ?
My problem is how to find out item type in createBinding procedure, as I do not have available item position there, but I need it to get item type to be able to inflate correct layout base on it.

```
@Override
    protected ChatMessageItemBinding createBinding(ViewGroup parent) {
        MyItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.my_item, parent,
                false, dataBindingComponent);


        return binding;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for the [DataBoundListAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/common/DataBoundListAdapter.kt) I can see that create binding is just a call from `onCreateViewHolder` which contains the information you need - `viewType: Int`

The simplest option for you is to override what the method is doing in your own adapter, to pass the type information you need.

```
@Override
DataBoundViewHolder<V> onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Note: no call to super
    V binding = createBindingByType(parent, viewType) //this is a new method
    return DataBoundViewHolder(binding)
}

private ChatMessageItemBinding createBindingByType(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    @LayoutRes int layout;
    switch(viewType) {
        case ...:
            layout = R.layout.my_item;
            break;
        ...
    }
    return DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), layout, parent, false, dataBindingComponent);
}

@Override
protected ChatMessageItemBinding createBinding(ViewGroup parent) {
    throw new RuntimeException("This method should not be called with MyAdapter");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the same classes of [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample), I think one of the approaches could be to ignore `DataBoundListAdapter` and directly implement `ListAdapter` like this:

```
/**
 * A RecyclerView adapter for [Repo] class.
 */
class RepoListAdapterFor2Types(
        private val dataBindingComponent: DataBindingComponent,
        appExecutors: AppExecutors,
        private val showFullName: Boolean,
        private val repoClickCallback: ((Repo, viewType: Int) -> Unit)?
) : ListAdapter<Repo, DataBoundViewHolder<RepoItemBinding>>(
        AsyncDifferConfig.Builder<Repo>(
            object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Repo>() {
                override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Repo, newItem: Repo): Boolean {
                    return oldItem.owner == newItem.owner
                            && oldItem.name == newItem.name
                }

                override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Repo, newItem: Repo): Boolean {
                    return oldItem.description == newItem.description
                            && oldItem.stars == newItem.stars
                }
        })
        .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(appExecutors.diskIO())
        .build()
) {

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val repo = getItem(position)
        //this is just for the example
        return when (repo.id) {
            1 -> 1
            else -> 2
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataBoundViewHolder<RepoItemBinding> {
        val binding = createBinding(parent, viewType)
        return DataBoundViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataBoundViewHolder<RepoItemBinding>, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.repo = getItem(position)
        holder.binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    private fun createBinding(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RepoItemBinding {
        @LayoutRes val layout = when (viewType) {
            1 -> R.layout.repo_item_type_1
            else -> R.layout.repo_item_type_2
        }
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<RepoItemBinding>(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            layout,
            parent,
            false,
            dataBindingComponent
        )
        binding.showFullName = showFullName
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            binding.repo?.let {
                repoClickCallback?.invoke(it, viewType)
            }
        }
        return binding
    }
}
```

If you need to work with completely different items use something different. You wont be able to have 2 diff callbacks so you should probably write your own `ListAdapter` implementation